# Issue with tab index when adding another row to table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**Summary of the problem**

My goal is to be able to add a new table row with my JavaScript function addRow() and have the tab index work correctly. When you add a new row it jumps from row[0]cell[0] to row[4]cell[0].

**Actual results**

When the page initially loads there are 4 rows. There tab index are shown below

Row 1 Tab Index: 2,3,4

Row 2 Tab Index: 12,13,14

Row 3 Tab Index: 22,23,24

Row 4 Tab Index: 32,33,34

If you click in the first cell and press tab you will go from cell to cell.

It then wraps around to the first cell in the second row and continues on. This part works fine.

The issue is with my addRow() function below. It adds rows fine but it resets the tabindex. As shown below

Row 1 Tab Index: 2,3,4

Row 2 Tab Index: 12,13,14

Row 3 Tab Index: 22,23,24

Row 4 Tab Index: 32,33,34

Row 5 Tab Index: 32,33,34

Row 6 Tab Index: 2,3,4

My overall question is how can I modify adRowsTable.addrow to give each cell in the new row a tab index that is 10 more then the previous rows.

**Javascript**

```js
function adRowsTable(id){
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var me = this;
  if(document.getElementById(id)){
    var row1 = table.rows[1].outerHTML;
    
     row1 = row1.replace(/value=/g, "noval=");
      row1 = row1.replace(/selected=/g, "noselect=");
      row1 = row1.replace(/useforjsadd/g, "selected=selected");
      row1 = row1.replace(/jsaddnoval/g, "value");
   
      
    //adds index-id in cols with class .tbl_id
    function setIds(){
      var tbl_id = document.querySelectorAll('#'+ id +' .tbl_id');
      for(var i=0; i<tbl_id.length; i++) tbl_id[i].innerHTML = i+1;
           
    }

    //add row after clicked row; receives clicked button in row
    me.addRow = function(btn){
      btn ? btn.parentNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', row1): table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',row1);  
        setIds();
    }
  }
}
    
//create object of adRowsTable(), pass the table id
var ob_adRows = new adRowsTable('table1');
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Table tabindex with javascript issue</h2>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      
    <td><input tabindex="2"></td>
    <td><input tabindex="3"></td>
    <td><input tabindex="4"></td>
  </tr>
    <?php $tabindex = $tabindex + 10?>
  <tr>
    <td><input tabindex="12"></td>
    <td><input tabindex="13"></td>
    <td><input tabindex="14"></td>
  </tr>
    <?php $tabindex = $tabindex + 10?>
  <tr>
    <td><input tabindex="22"></td>
    <td><input tabindex="23"></td>
    <td><input tabindex="24"></td>
  </tr>
    <?php $tabindex = $tabindex + 10?>
  <tr>
    <td><input tabindex="32"></td>
    <td><input tabindex="33"></td>
    <td><input tabindex="34"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <button type="button" onclick="ob_adRows.addRow()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If anyone is able to help I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I have still been working on this to no avail. I am considoring offering a boutnty if that is possible